# How to get global notifications list in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, push-notification, notifications

Trying to get **list of notifications** in my extension, **who are blocked/ allowed in chrome settings**
 (chrome://settings/content/notifications)-[notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWFm9.png).

I can get the value of status with  `chrome.contentSettings.notifications.get()`, but for that a need to know primary url. Maybe someone have done this before?

Comment: Might be useful: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications#method-getAll

Comment: but this returns only my own notifications id, and i cant reach other notifications info